# Load Balancing in ASP.NET MVC Web Application. What can/can't be done?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, load-balancing

I'm in the middle of developing a web application and have been asked the question whether it will work with a load balancer. My initial reaction is yes, since there is no state tracked between requests anywhere in the system. However, there is some application specific state loaded on app start (configuration settings from the database mainly.)

1. This data is all Read Only. Is it sufficient to rely on the normal cache dependency mechanisms to manage this and invalidate these objects across all the applications in the cluster or would I have to move to a shared cache system like App Fabric to ensure reliability/consistency?
2. With diagnostics enabled, I've got numerous logging calls using EventSource.Write and an out of process logger picking these up. I assume in this case, I'd need one logger installed on each of the servers in the cluster to pick up the events each one triggers. I'm not too fussed about that, but what is a good way to identify which server in the cluster serviced the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you initialize the data on each server seperately and it is read-only, there's no problem. The separate applications will have a copy each.
2. Yes, you'd need a logger on each instance. In order to identify the server you could include the servers' IP into the log. That way you can track the server. (provided you have static IP's, but I assume you do).